# Does "risk score" always have to be a numerical value?

Tags: risk

In the context of organisational IT security, for a threat such as the insider threat, is it actually okay to report (in a risk assessment) as "Risk Score=Medium" or does "risk score" always have to be of an numerical value?

Answer (score 18):

No, qualitative risk scores need not be numeric. Numbers, in fact, can be a problem as they tend to encourage using quantitative methods on measures that are not quantified. But that may be an issue I am more concerned about than a lot of risk professionals.

So, as long as your qualitative measures are well-defined and communicated, you are using valid methods.

**However**, in my experience, managers like to see risk communications in the format that they are used to seeing. So, you might get better traction with decision-makers by using what they expect to see, be it numbers or qualitative terms.

Comment: It's much harder to aggregate "Medium" as opposed to a 5, but exactly like this answer said, it is up to the specific manager and whether they care about specifics of the metric, and what they want to do with them.

Comment: @Nelson renaming "medium" to 5 does not magically turn it into a number you can do math with, despite appearances. You're still operating on an ordinal scale.

Comment: @tom a point few people understand, unfortunately, even Seiersen in his now famous book

Answer (score 6):

The word "score" implies a numeric value, and is normally used to denote something numeric. If you were going to go with something like low/medium/high then terms like "risk level", "risk rating" or "severity" would be a more common.

But honestly, it doesn't really matter. No one is going to be confused by you saying that the "risk score" is medium (although they might be pedantic about it).

Comment: Implies, but not strongly. MW (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/score) lists GRADE as a synonym, and grades are A-F in some countries.

Comment: @Tom Synonyms aren't always 100% perfect. If you look up "current", you will find synonyms like "ongoing" or "present", yet people will look at you strangely if you talk about "electrical ongoing" (which actually happened in my class last week with a non-native speaking student using google translate). These examples are more extreme than score vs grade are in this context, but I would still be careful deciding right or wrong usage based on synonyms.

Comment: @Tom that page lists "grade" as a synonym for the *verb* score, rather than the noun which is what we're talking about here. Other synonyms it lists include "twenty", "grudge" and "a copy of a musical composition in written or printed notation".

Comment: Folks, let's stay within the topic boundaries: https://www.openriskmanual.org/wiki/Qualitative_Rating_Score, https://safetyculture.com/topics/qualitative-and-quantitative-risk-analysis/ , Qualitative scores don't strongly imply a number. "Medium" is a score that can be assigned to a risk, threat, or vulnerability based on analysis. It's what the subject *archives* or *earns* based on analysis. Hence, "score" is the correct term rather than "level", which is the grade of the measure that's used to assign a score.

Comment: OP asked a question about terminology, and in English the noun "score" strongly implies a numeric value. I have never heard someone say that a score is "medium" or "B" or "good".

Answer (score 5):

No. In fact, using the term “risk score” in the context of qualitative risk assessments may be **misleading**. This term often appears when risk is expressed as a relationship between likelihood (e.g., frequency of attacks) and consequence (e.g., impact, severity), and is commonly combined with **risk matrices**: `Risk = Likelihood × Consequence`, where likelihood and consequence are employed as x and y axes. The two dimensional matrix also often serves as a heatmap to better illustrate different levels of risk (e.g., high, medium, low).

Without attempting to hijack this question, I want to make you aware of a few problems related to risk matrices and point you to relevant literature. Apart from the general problem that different interpretations of qualifiers (e.g., what is high risk?) may exist, there is limited evidence that risk matrices actually improve decision-making (Cox, 2008, 2009). Coming back to your original question, I assume that the `Risk Score=Medium` was somehow obtained based on likelihood and consequence. In general, manipulating ordinal data using mathematical operators is not allowed. Furthermore, the multiplication operator creates lines of equal risk that a matrix cannot capture well (Pickering and Cowley, 2010).

**References**

- *Anthony (Tony) Cox Jr, L. (2008). What's wrong with risk matrices?. Risk Analysis: An International Journal, 28(2), 497-512.*
- *Cox, L. A. (2009). Limitations of risk assessment using risk matrices. Risk analysis of complex and uncertain systems, 101-124.*
- *Pickering, A., & Cowley, S. P. (2010). Risk Matrices: implied accuracy and false assumptions. J. Health Saf. Res. Pract, 2, 11-18.*

A practical take on this topic can also be found in:

- *Hubbard, D. W., & Seiersen, R. (2023). How to measure anything in cybersecurity risk. John Wiley & Sons.*
- *Freund, J., & Jones, J. (2014). Measuring and managing information risk: a FAIR approach. Butterworth-Heinemann.*

Comment: If I never had to use (or create) a risk matrix ever again ...

Comment: @schroeder Relatable. It seems that FAIR gains wider industry adoption though. In research, quantifying security risk is quite active. See, for example, [SoK: Quantifying Cyber Risk](https://www.danielwoods.info/assets/pdf/WB2020_sok_cyberrisk_snp.pdf).

Comment: @schroeder You are welcome. Actually, two years ago, I did a quite comprehensive multivocal literature review on Value at Risk (VaR) models in information security (covering > 60 papers). Unfortunately, I never managed to publish it due to other research obligations. Let me know in case you want to read it.

Comment: I do! can you link here?

Comment: @schroeder I have not (yet) published a preprint since it's a literature review and needs an update (it lacks papers that have been published in the past 2-3 years). Please send me an e-mail if you would like to have it.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you also provide and follow a guideline of what "medium risk" actually means and make sure that anyone reading your report knows about that guideline.

But the same applies to any other unit of measure. A risk score of "5.73" is not any more or less meaningful than "medium" when not accompanied by a guideline of how that is to be interpreted.

The general formula for risk assessment in IT infrastructure is `risk = likelihood * impact`. "Likelihood" can be quantified as a probability for an event to happen within a given timespan. "Impact" can be quantified by estimating the sum of all material and immaterial costs for the business if that event occurs.

For example, "User forgot their password" should be very high likelihood but very low cost for the business. While "Datacenter gets destroyed by a natural disaster" should be very low likelihood but very high cost for the business. So those two scenarios might actually end up with unintuitively similar risk scores.

Comment: FWIW, this is how [Torino asteroid impact scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torino_scale) works.

Comment: The problem is that `risk = likelihood * impact` isn't actually a formula. It's a relationship. Plopping numbers in and multiplying them doesn't create a "quantified" risk calculation, which is why "user forgetting" and "asteroid" can end up with the same score and create confusion. But, as I say in my answer, few cyber risk professionals are concerned about the consequences of that.

Answer (score 1):

No, and most of the so-called "risk score" values are actually misleading and mathematically wrong.

First, there is only one cybersecurity standard that I am aware of that specifically describes a numerical "risk score" or similar value as being numerical, that being IEC 62443 with it's "security level" concept. Other standards such as ISO 27001 leave it entirely up to you what kind of risk assessment and rating method you wish to use. They may make suggestions and provide examples, but do not make any particular method binding. So you are free to choose, and if you choose to make a purely qualitative assessment with verbal categories, that is absolutely fine.

Second, do not be tricked into thinking that the string "1" is identical to the number 1. Most risk scoring methods define **qualitative** categories, i.e. they define an **ordinal scale** for things like probability and impact, and then assign words like "low", "medium", etc. to those as well as a numbering such as 1, 2, 3. They then multiply or sum those numbers up to acquire a "risk score". This is **wrong**. Ordinal scales do not have multiplication or addition defined. You can't multiply, say, house numbers and derive any meaningful result. Risk scores are house numbers - they simply order something. House number 25 is further along the street than house number 11. And probability 3 is higher than probability 1. That is all you can say about them on an ordinal scale.

So pick your method and apply it properly. If you rate things as "medium" etc. then don't do math on that. If you want correct numbers, use a correct quantitative method such as [FAIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis_of_information_risk). To identify proper quantitative methods from snakeoil pseudo-math, check if the number has a **unit**, such as "estimated damage in $ per year".

(and for the love of god, if you make quasi-quantitative categories, at least use a logarithmic scale [so your risk matrices end up being less wrong](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5432360_What%27s_Wrong_with_Risk_Matrices).)

Comment: To be fair (pardon the pun), you need the underlying data to support a quantitative measure. Qualitative measures are valid as long as they remain qualitative. And that's where, I think, people get into trouble. They see the value in quantitative measures, like FAIR, and then cram whatever data they have into the model, and violate both the qualitative and quantitative approaches. I tore a McKinsey analyst article to pieces online for suggesting that those who use qualitative measures are "immature" and "lazy". If you don't have data, there is only so much you can do.

Comment: @schroeder `"[...] you need the underlying data to support a quantitative measure [...]"`. I think one of the key takeaways of Hubbard's book or FAIR is that you can still use the 'same' subjective estimates with quantitative measures; you just have the added benefit of making uncertainty explicit.

Comment: @schroeder Matthias an me read the same books. One of Hubbard's insights is that when it comes to data that you have more than you think and you need less than you believe. Yes, you need data. But you can make fairly good guesses from data you already have or can easily get. Most people just find it easier to look at a wall and go "uh. let's say it's a 3".

Comment: @MatthiasA.Eckhart `you just have the added benefit of making uncertainty explicit` except Hubbard only does that academically, which is my concern. Yes, it is possible, but the book goes on to violate the separation of qualitative and quantitative data to make everything "look" quantitative without the explicit uncertainty.

Comment: @schroeder `"[...] the book goes on to violate the separation of qualitative and quantitative data [...]"`. Do you have a reference (page number)? I would be really curious where this happens.

Comment: @schroeder Hubbard does it in a simplified way. FAIR uses a better method. I've also described a similar approach in my book (which is in German, so might be of no use to you). I do agree that making uncertainty explicit is an important part of qualitative risk analysis, as is communicating it properly so a statistical risk of, say 125,784 $/year doesn't look like an exact number you know for sure. But that's beside the point here.